# Jquery : fadein function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am following jquery video tutorial for image slider. This is what i've in html

```
   <div id="slider">
     <img id="1" src="images/1.jpg" alt="" > 
     <img id="2" src="images/2.jpg" alt="" /> 
     <img id="3" src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>
     <img id="4" src="images/4.jpg" alt=""/>
   </div>
```

**css for images**

```
#slider >img{
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
    display: none;
    float: left;
 }
```

i want to fadein  first image when  page loads like this

```
$(function(){
      $("#slider>img>#1").fadeIn(3000);
  });
```

but this does not work. i did inspect jquery files is also included perfectly in my sources. can someone help me with it please

Comment: `ids` should be both unique and *not* starting with a number.

Comment: thas  unique  in my editor  actually a typo here

Comment: They are still starting with a number.

Comment: also your selector is wrong even if you were using unique ids, `img>#1` means  an element with id `1` inside an img tag... probably meant to do `img#1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Images tags `<img>` cannot have children, so [`>` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) makes no sense. Correct code would be:

```
$("#slider>img#1").fadeIn(3000);
```

Another thing. Even though numeric ids are valid HTML5 identifiers, it's better to stick to more traditional ones, like `image-1` for example for legacy browsers:

```
<img id="image-1" src="images/1.jpg" alt="" >
```

Comment: Double check everything, it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/2hgs1vqs/. If not, then it's something else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div id="slider">
     <img id="img1" src="images/1.jpg" alt="" > 
     <img id="img2" src="images/2.jpg" alt="" /> 
     <img id="img3" src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>
     <img id="img4" src="images/4.jpg" alt=""/>
   </div>

$(function(){
      $("#img1").fadeIn(3000);
  });
```

Answer (score -2):

you have to use `$(document).ready(function () {...});`
This means that when the page is loaded, the function will be active. You should place your code in this function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#slider>img>#1").fadeIn(3000);
});
```

Comment: That's what `$(function()` does